# Bootstrap Thumbnail Cropping and Positioning

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, position, overflow, crop

I'm having these 3 images with different sizes. When I display them inside 3 containers like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {   
    <div class="avatar-container">
        <img class="avatar img-thumbnail" src="@Href("~/Content/Avatars/",item.Name+".jpg")" />  
    </div>
}
```

This is my CSS file:

```
div.avatar-container {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 70px;
}

.avatar {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And also **img-thumbnail** is from bootstrap.css (line 368). After a while I've managed to crop images (using **overflow** property) so that the each avatar is displayed as 70x50 thumbnail.

Take a look at these 3 returned thumbnails:  [image](https://goo.gl/photos/re864L85a8f7bBVSA)
**[PROBLEMS]**

**image1.** It also cropped the nice bottom part of my thumbnail.
**image2.** Well I would think that thumbnails are squares, not rectangles.
**image3.** How do I crop to the middle of the image (in both vertically and horizontally manners)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, using JavaScript and another thumbnail container.

```
@*HTML-----------------------------------------------*@
@foreach (var item in Model) {   
    <div class="avatar-container">
        <div class="img-thumbnail">
            <img class="avatar img-thumbnail" src="@Href("~/Content/Avatars/",item.Name+".jpg")" />  
        </div>
    </div>
}
@*JavaScript-----------------------------------------*@
//If the image has greater Width => display as landscape
<script>
        $(".avatar").each(function () {
            if (this.naturalWidth > this.naturalHeight) {
                $(this).addClass("landscape");
            }
        });
</script>
@*CSS------------------------------------------------*@
//That big container outside
div.avatar-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 70px;
    height:70px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
//And here's the extra thumbnail container
div.img-thumbnail{
    width:100% !important;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#e1dada;
}
//This is for the actual image
.img-thumbnail{
    padding:1px !important;
}
//This one sets the image as a portrait
.avatar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
//This one helps setting up the image horizontally
.landscape{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

The final results look like [this](https://goo.gl/photos/cJ1TTDgpmL7B83kZ9)